# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS restore mssing critical components

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, python, dependencies

Attempt to upgrade hplip encountered missing dependencies.  Advised to purge python and python3 removed critical components.
I can login via recovery mode. Advice to try:
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

resulted in a list of selected packages and failed with the error message:
"The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libpython3.8-stdlib (=3.8.5-1~20.04.2) but 3.8.6-1+bionic1 is to be installed.
E: Unable to correct problem, you have broken packages."

Suggestions?

Comment: First, discount future advice from that source -- purging the originally-installed 20.04 version of Python3 is rarely the right answer.

Comment: Second, version `3.8.6-1+bionic1` is not coming from an Ubuntu source, and it says 'bionic' (18.04) right there in the version string. Anything from that non-Ubuntu source is unlikely to be compatible with your 20.04 system. Advice: Uninstall all 18.04 packages from that particular source. Reinstall Python2 and Python3 packages only from the Ubuntu repositories.